# How to insert an initial value in column of longtext type in mysql command

Tags: mysql, longtext

This is the default of the table:

```
desc extender_device; 
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sn                      | varchar(16)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| syncing_stage           | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| created_at              | datetime(6)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| updated_at              | datetime(6)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

If I was to insert an entry on that table on sql command where the syncing_stage is of blank text, What is the sql looks like. here is the one I have tried and failed:

```
insert into extender_device ( sn, syncing_stage) values ( 'AX123', '{}');
```

as **I am using the wrong data for the "syncing_stage" column.**

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: just to be sure: you tried it without "value"? Like so: "... ( sn, syncing_stage) values ( 'A..." Syntax looks wrong to me.

Comment: You need to fill in the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns, because they don't allow `NULL` and the default is `NULL`.

Comment: remove the "value"  word

Comment: 1)  Yes, I want to insert into "syncing_stage" field with an empty value. 2) Sorry, my initial given SQL  was of wrong format, and I have it corrected above, but the issue stays.  3) IN my DB, the data on created_at and updated_at fields are auto generated, when a new entry is inserted.

Comment: How do you auto generate values for [created_at] and [updated_at]? Like @Barmar says, your table design shows something different.

Comment: They can only be auto-generated if they're timestamps, with `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: If you want to insert an empty value use `''` rather than `'{}'`

Comment: @Barmar while I agree, '{}' should work too. User3595231, for testing you could set NULL to "YES" for [created_at] and [updated_at] in your table design. If that makes it work, you can implement the solution Barmar offers with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: For "updated_at and "created_at",  I remember there was some defined trigger when there is insert or update on any row in that table. Anyway, This was not the cause of my failure. Barmar's last solution have my problem solved.

Comment: @Sam020 Why would `{}` work? They said they want to insert blank text, that's not blank.

Comment: @Barmar and that's why I agreed with you, but I interpreted "failed" in the OP as if there was an error of some sort, and while '{}' doesn't result in an empty field, it shouldn't give an error.

Comment: @Sam020 I interpreted it as "failed to achieve the desired result".

Comment: which was the right interpretation ;)